# tomcat too many files

Tags: tomcat

I get the following after a day using tomcat:

```
java    25006 root  996r  FIFO        0,6            894580 pipe
java    25006 root  997w  FIFO        0,6            894586 pipe
java    25006 root  998r  FIFO        0,6            894587 pipe
java    25006 root 1000r  FIFO        0,6            894588 pipe
java    25006 root 1001w  FIFO        0,6            894599 pipe
java    25006 root 1002r  FIFO        0,6            894600 pipe
java    25006 root 1003r   REG      254,6        0  8570556 /usr/share/apache-tomcat-5.5.30/temp/prn1614392207033974759xc (deleted)
java    25006 root 1004r  FIFO        0,6            894601 pipe
java    25006 root 1005w  FIFO        0,6            894607 pipe
java    25006 root 1006r  FIFO        0,6            894608 pipe
java    25006 root 1007r   REG      254,6        0  8570557 /usr/share/apache-tomcat-5.5.30/temp/prn1736781771548325427xc (deleted)
java    25006 root 1008r  FIFO        0,6            894609 pipe
java    25006 root 1009w  FIFO        0,6            894617 pipe
java    25006 root 1010r  FIFO        0,6            894618 pipe
java    25006 root 1011r   REG      254,6        0  8570558 /usr/share/apache-tomcat-5.5.30/temp/prn8390558105456339721xc (deleted)
```

The entire application was reviewed for unclosed streams several times.

Using tomcat 5.5.30 and JRE 6u21. Not using AntiJarLocking and AntiResourceLocking (any combination result in the same thing).

Is there a java tool to track down the code that open closeable streams within Java code? What are these pipes? Could it be unclosed connections to the database server (using C3P0)

Arth

Comment: Maybe `strace` utility will provide you some clues. (see here http://serverfault.com/questions/222669/how-do-i-run-strace-or-ltrace-on-tomcat-catalina)

Answer (score 1):

The Too many open files message occurs on UNIX® and Linux® operating systems. The default setting for the maximum number of open files might be **too low**.

To avoid this condition, increase the maximum open files to 8000 by completing these steps:

```
Edit the /etc/security/limit.conf file.
```

Change the statement that specifies the value of nofiles to **8000**.
Optional: If you want the change to take effect in the current session, type

```
ulimit -n 8000.
```